# Is it best to shield/ground an SSD in a laptop when the HDD was shielded/grounded?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata, ground

I recently replaced a 2.5" SATA HDD in a laptop with a 2.5" SATA SSD.

The HDD had thin piece of flexible metallic foil attached to it via adhesive and 2 screws.  The foil had a lead that then got screwed into the motherboard.  I'm guessing this was to shield or ground the HDD.

The SSD has screw holes in the same positions as the HDD, so I could, in theory, remove the foil from the HDD and screw it into the SSD.  The only trick will be removing the foil from the HDD because the adhesive is, well, very sticky.

Would it be best to apply the metallic foil to the SSD and screw it in, or not use the foil at all?

Here is an example photograph (not the exact drive I replaced, but similar):

[image: Metallic foil on hard disk drive]

Comment: One of the pins on the SSD will be ground and you should not have to ground separately. Same for HDD as far as that goes and I have not seen foil grounds on hard drives.

Comment: Suspect the foil was more about [hampering](https://www.google.com/search?q=hampering) the sound from the HDD rather than providing grounding and/or EM protection. **I also seriously doubt a thing piece of metallic foil was being used as a ground for anything.**

Comment: Knowing consumer electronics the foil was probably for EMC purposes so that the drive motor wasn't basically emitting noise at some frequency multiple of the motor speed. Or the switch mode power supply in the laptop that powered the drive is noisy (RF wise) and they were shielding that. Basically to create a sealed faraday cage. Most home users probably wouldn't notice a difference with it there or not.

Comment: @Ramhound I've been to an EMC test house. We definitely use foil to ground random bits to make things bomb proof from an EMC perspective and then end up sticking with the foil because we don't want to go back to the test house for another run. EMC is expensive. :)

Comment: @Mokubai - I suppose I got tainted on a bunch of "floating" grounds on $500K testing equipment, that made it impossible, to use the testing software on the station.

Comment: By floating ground, I mean a huge ground pole going to through the certain of the station, but the pole itself wasn't connected to a true ground.

Comment: @Mokubai Interesting. You mentioned 2 possibilities: (1) That the foil is to restrict RF noise coming from the HDD. Since the HDD was replaced with the SSD, I'm thinking that is no longer an issue, so the foil could be omitted. (2) That the foil is to shield RF noise from the power supply to the drive. Hmmm... that one seems possibly relevant given that the power supply was not changed. If the RF noise could have caused problems with the HDD (they added the foil and screws for *some* reason), could it lead to problems with the SSD?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket almost definitely not a problem. Most of the time spent in the test house is fighting to suppress one or two minor peaks in emissions that coincide with the frequency of your switch mode power supply or some harmonic of your radio transmission (wifi etc). They are very rarely harmful to the actual electronics but limits are set at levels where particularly sensitive equipment *might* be affected. SSDs are designed to be inside a computer chassis and "in the thick of it" with all the other components, I doubt it will be affected.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks.  I've always been curious about the amount of noise "inside the box".

Comment: I'd say if it was easy to transfer then go for it, if not then just ignore it. You'll either find out pretty quick that it needs the shielding because your Wi-Fi goes unreliable, your lap suddenly feels like it is being microwaved, and your *old CRT* TV starts playing up, or you'll never notice the difference. It's probably no worse than having a mobile phone in your house.

Comment: Others state it, but it is most likely shielding for U.S. FCC requirements. If you ever open an “off the shelf” USB powered external hard drive brought in the U.S. for the U.S. market and open it up, the drive is _always_ seemingly wrapped in stuff like that. Peel it all off and you will see a hard drive with a SATA or IDE to USB bridge board beneath that stuff. The drive will operate the same without it.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be best to apply the metallic foil to the SSD and screw it
> in, or not use the foil at all?

I had time to quickly take apart my X230 laptop with HDD and the covers off my M70s desktop with SSD card in a socket (main drive C:) and a Samsung SSD drive in the drive bay.

None of the drives in either machine have separate grounds. (Take care with extra grounds lest they incur a ground loop).

Further, in my experience with customer machines I also have not seen drives grounded separately.

One of the pins on the SSD will be ground and you should not have to ground separately.

You should not experience any difficulty installing the drive normally.

Comment: I've seen it on some older HP laptops, but definitely not on all of them. Can't say for sure if its for ground or noise reduction though.